# Is Digital Product key and Hard disk pre-installed with Windows 8.1 dependent on each other?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, oem

I replaced motherboard for my laptop, so I lost the Digital Product key, as a result of which I am not able to activate Windows.
I would like to entirely format the hard disk including the partitions (reserved OEM and recovery).

If i perform a fresh install of Windows 8.1 with an iso downloaded from the Microsoft website and put the product key which I can get from Dell (laptop brand), does it work or does it work only with the Windows 8.1 that came with the Laptop?

Comment: Generally the Windows OEM licenses are tied to the motherboard, as you pointed out. If it is an OEM or a System Builder license indeed, you could try using the automated phone in order to re-activate the key on your new installation ID.

Comment: @fragamemnon I tried, but it says Wrong installation ID.

Comment: Can you try with `slmgr /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX` (obviously replacing with your ID)? If not, manual activation over the phone?

Comment: You shouldn't have to enter the license key for Windows 8.1, the installer, will automatically detect the license stored in the firmware, and automatically activate.  If it does not you simply call the Activation Center and activate by phone.  Of course you shouldn't have to reinstall Windows to reactivate your installation.  [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowkeyPlus) will allow you to view the embedded license key.  Once you know the key, simply change the installation's key to that key, and activate the installation manually/by phone.

Comment: If the motherboard was not replaced with an OEM Dell motherboard, then you don't currently have a Windows 8.1 license, your (OEM) license rights were connected to the motherboard itself.

Answer (score 0):

When Dell (or any other brand, for that matter) replaces motherboard in a system with Windows 8/8.1 preinstalled they also provide new key for that motherboard. Because, yes, new one does not have the digital key stored on it.

If you did it on your own - tough luck if you did not checked if the replacement came with new key.

Are you sure you can get key from Dell? If yes, then no problem - the key will work with media downloaded from Microsoft. The way MS set up the Digital Product Key means that there's no more distinction between OEM and Box (or other types) of licensing from the POV of (re)installation process. You have to provide the key, no matter if it's on Motherboard (which is automated) or on a sticker (which is manual).

EDIT: Without DPK stored on the motherboard the OEM Recovery files that are on the HD will restore system to OOBE state, that will ask for DPK after first logon. So no - deleting those files by formatting whole drive will not make disaster you're in right now any bigger...

Comment: Dell did not replace my motherboard, but a third-party installed a new motherboard for me. I think I may not get the key from DELL.

Comment: Does formatting the entire harddisk including the OEM, Windows installation files create a disaster so that I would never be able to activate Windows again without buying a new one? Is it mandatory to retain those partitions in Hard disk?

Comment: http://www.dell.com/support/contents/in/en/inbsdt1/videos/videoPlayer/ozYWl5ZDp9bMIvOj0Pt8qy24pFVxAM3Z in this video, they entered a new product key. If DPK is a card as shown in the video, then I didn't have that card. I didn't receive it when I bought my DELL laptop

Comment: If I have the DPK card, can I completely format the hard disk including those DELL partitions? Is DPK card key different from the normal product key?

Comment: You should then ask the third-party for the DPK card. If your laptop came with W8/8.1 then they should provide you with DPK card (unless you knew that won't be the case). Dell may or may not provide you with one, and if yes they may charge you for it.
DPK on card like the one on linked media is normal (in every sense of the work), fully working and valid key. As for rest: see edited answer.